# Eclipse 3.7 cannot install any plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I just installed eclipse 3.7 and cannot install any plugins. In the dropins folder, from the market place or the software install option. Find-bugs, sub-eclipse, google plug in etc..., none will install. I keep getting a message like this:

Unable to read repository at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.18.jar.

I tried installing jboss tools and got this:

Unable to read repository at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/JBossTools-3.3.0.M3/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate.ui_3.4.0.v20110915-1559-H24-M3.jar.

If anybody knows how to fix this please let me know, I tried everything, unchecking the software updates in preferences. starting as an admin, re installing eclipse, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try to open that URLs in a browser to see whether the problem is related with Eclipse or not.

Answer (score 0):

The message that you are getting sounds like you are not adding the correct url to the update manager.  Did you use this:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.18.jar

or this:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/

as the url for subclipse?  The latter is correct.